# Bootstrap 3 dropdown events not firing

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to get an shown event fired at dropdown at this site running on BS3.0

http://hmelius.com/avant/index.php

I have tried this code in the console (from the BS3 documentation page) but with no luck

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {
  console.log("shown");
});
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I believe the events fire on the "parent" not the toggle, so it would be the element above the toggle with `.dropdown` or `.btn-group`; the dropdown wrapping element

take a look at the source to see what I mean: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/dropdown.js

Comment: glad to help! remember to "accept" the answer it it worked for you, for future reference!

Comment: yes. there just was a time limit before which I could. accepted :)

Comment: Not triggering on any element :/

Answer (score 9):

Based on @monastic-panic 's comment this works

```
$(".dropdown-toggle").parent().on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
  console.log("shown");
});
```