# Add callback to Bootstrap-select

Tags: bootstrap-select

I am using [Bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/3/) in my project. Is it possible to add a callback when Select has been opened? Code below does not work.

```
var sp = $.fn.selectpicker.constructor.prototype.show;
$.fn.selectpicker.constructor.prototype.show = function () {
  sp.call(this);
  if (this.options.callback) {
    //console.log('is callback!');
    this.options.callback();
  }
};
$('.selectpicker-state').selectpicker({
  title: null,
  callback: function() {
    alert('show!');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the bootstrap dropdown event `shown`
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns and see the Events section

```
$('#myDropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
    // do something…
})
```

Comment: Yes. I tried it. but it looks that the event does not fire. I tried to bind a handler with a delay, but it did not help. I still look for the reason. Thank you!

Comment: Try the other events. I think that some of them should work, because bootstrap-select keep all of the bootstrap dropdown behavior

Comment: Yes. According to the documentation the event fires on the "parent" not the toggle.
Thank you for your time!

Help here:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936181/bootstrap-3-dropdown-events-not-firing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19936181/bootstrap-3-dropdown-events-not-firing)
and/or here
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857779/process-for-using-show-bs-dropdown-in-bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857779/process-for-using-show-bs-dropdown-in-bootstrap)